# Jquery form submit open new tab simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I have created a html form where I used this html and js code which populate form value to a link and submit to another website.

```
<form>
<table width="505" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="324">Your name</td>
            <td width="165"><input type="text" name="applicant_UserName" id="name2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Your email address</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="applicant_Email" id="email2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Your mobile number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="applicant_mobile number" id="mobile number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>What is the name of the person you want to nominate as your guarantor?</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Guarantor applicant_UserName" id="name3" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and js

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        var out_url = "https://demo.com/PowerFormSigning.aspx?";
        e.preventDefault();
        var arr  = $('input[type="text"]')
            .map(function(){
            var self = $(this);
            return [self.attr('name'),
                self.val()
           ].join('=');
        })
        .toArray()
        .concat($("option:selected").map(function(){
                var self = $(this);
                return [self.closest('select').attr('name'), self.text()].join('=')
            }).toArray()).join('&');
        window.location.href = out_url + arr;
        
    })
    
})
```

Now I want that another new tab will open simultaneously by clicking the submit where it will show the message "data submitted" with few css styles. I tried some codes but it opens new window and sometimes browser is blocking the window. Please help me to solve the issue that when submitted, a redirection to new tab with the message "data submitted"with few styles will open in the browser.

Comment: You should probably be creating modals / alerts on your own than trying to create a new browser window. Popups are usually blocked on modern browsers by default.

Comment: yes. I tried codes to open a new tab but was not working. only new window/popup code was working.

Comment: You can't control how browsers handle opening new window/tab, therefor as @nkprince007 suggested you should use an overlay popup instead. https://codepen.io/adrienlochon/pen/Jgjrx